# Yii auth with aply dynamic bizrules

Tags: authentication, yii

I am using Yii auth extension for user's authentication wise can get access.

In initial level of auth module only describe give operations,assignment,task according to user role.

I want give task according to bizrule at assign by user can access(update,listing,delete) own data.

I want to change one file for apply bizrule
AuthFilter.php

class AuthFilter extends CFilter
{

```
public $params = array();
public $enableBizRule = true;
public $enableBizRuleData = true;

protected function preFilter($filterChain)
{
    $itemName = '';
    $controller = $filterChain->controller;


    $user = Yii::app()->getUser();


    if (($module = $controller->getModule()) !== null) {

        $itemName .= $module->getId() . '.';
        if ($user->checkAccess($itemName . '*')) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $itemName .= $controller->getId();
    //print_r($itemName);
    if ($user->checkAccess($itemName . '.*')) {
        return true;
    }

    $itemName .= '.' . $controller->action->getId();

    if ($user->checkAccess($itemName, $this->params)) {
        return true;
    }


    if ($user->isGuest) {
        $user->loginRequired();
    }

    throw new CHttpException(401, Yii::t('yii', 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'));
}
```

}

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth/
http://www.cniska.net/yii-auth/en_us/auth/assignment/index